# Unable to load file with file size more than 20MB even though maxFilesize is set to 500 in DropZone

Tags: javascript, c#, html

```
for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
                {
                    HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[i];
                    //Save file content goes here
                    fName = file.FileName;
                    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
                    {
}}
```

above is my C# code to fetch the files and save to custom path.

```
Dropzone.options.dropzoneForm = {
            autoProcessQueue: false,
            uploadMultiple: true,
            parallelUploads: 100,
            maxFiles: 100,
            maxFilesize: 500,
            acceptedFiles: 'image/jpeg,image/png,image/tiff,application/pdf,.pdf,.jpeg,.jpg,.tiff,.tif,.pdf',
            init: function () {}}
```

Above is my java script code for dropzone. Here I have given maxFilesize as 500MB and I am trying to upload file of 22MB size, getting error as "Maximum request length exceeded" in C# and Request.Files.Count is showing 0 count. Please help me on this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could the error message be coming from IIS? There is a limitation of max upload size.

Comment: What is `maxAllowedContentLength` in your web.config file?

Comment: No I have not yet published the site to IIS, running the site locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It allow to upload file with max size of 2GB. update this setting in web.config file

```
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="2147483" executionTimeout="1600" requestLengthDiskThreshold="2147483647" />
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483647" />
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: thanks for information it is working fine I am able to save the file.